# how to get all combinations of records rather then distinct using pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have records in a #table like this:
[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THKB1.jpg)

i use pivot on the table so that i get each "commenttypes" in separate columns.
as you can see that there are two sets of records for SuiteNumber 100, but when i implement pivot,

```
 SELECT  SuiteNumber ,
        UserName ,
        [Source Comments] AS SourceComments ,
        [Transaction Comments] AS TransactionComments ,
        [Confirmation Notes] AS ConfirmationNotes
FROM    #ToPivot PIVOT
( MAX(CommentsName) FOR CommentType IN ( [Source Comments],
                                         [Transaction Comments],
                                         [Confirmation Notes] ) ) AS p
```

it only outputs 1 record against suiteNumber 100 which is obvious,[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn0qB.jpg)
but for me it is problematic as i have to show all the comments against all suitnumbers whether repeating or not.
i tried case statement but it is not helping in the desired results.
any help would be appreciated.
I am new here, so please tolerate any mistakes regarding Question.
thankyou much in advance

Comment: `PIVOT` doesn't work this way. Inside `IN` you have to enumerate literals not column names.

Comment: @Giorgos if you see the PIVOT TABLE image link, Pivot is working fine. except that it only returns 1 record against 100, but infact it has to return two records.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. But it is always better if you include table schema and table values as text in your question, instead of images.